# (13)Permission denied: Error retrieving pid file run/httpd.pid

Tags: apache, redhat

I have installed `httpd-2.2.29` using commands:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/user/httpd
make
make install
```

I configured `httpd.conf` and tried to start with `apache: apachectl start`. But got following error:

> (13)Permission denied: Error retrieving pid file run/httpd.pid
>       Remove it before continuing if it is corrupted.

I tried to find file `httpd.pid`, but where is no such file.

Could someone help me resolve such issue?

Answer (score 15):

Did you try and start apache as a non privileged user? Permission denied suggests that you did. Try this instead:

```
$ sudo apachectl start
```

Answer (score 3):

I use:

```
$ sudo service httpd start
```

In the place of start you can put stop, restart, and etc.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, service was in running mode, I used restart command

`$ sudo apachectl restart`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I fixed it with the following:

```
sudo killall httpd
```

Verified that there were no other httpd-related processes running

```
ps -elf | grep httpd
```

Started the httpd service again

```
sudo service httpd start
```

Confirmed that the httpd service was running again

```
sudo service httpd status
```